# Getting "ValueError: invalid literal for int" when trying to make a GUI with tKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have worked on this a good bit and everything I try does not seem to fix the problem. I am relatively inexperienced with the nuances of this programing language. I appreciate any tips.

```
from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    lbltitle = Label(root, text="Adding Program")
    lbltitle.grid(row=0, column=3)

lbllabelinput = Label(root, text="Input first number")
lbllabelinput.grid(row=1, column=0)

entnum1 = Entry(root, text=1)
entnum1.grid(row=1, column=1)

lbllabelinput2 = Label(root, text="Input Second number")
lbllabelinput2.grid(row=1, column=2)

entnum2 = Entry(root, text=1)
entnum2.grid(row=1, column=3)


def callback():
    ent1 = entnum1.get()
    ent2 = entnum2.get()
    if ent1 != 0 and ent2 != 0:
                result = int(ent1) + int(ent2)
                lblresult = Label(root, text=str(result))
                lblresult.grid(row=3)

btnadd = Button(root, text="add", command=callback())
btnadd.grid(row=2)

root = mainloop()
```

here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matt9878/Google Drive/AddingProgram/AddingProgram.py", line 31, in <module>
    btnadd = Button(root, text="add", command=callback())
  File "/Users/matt9878/Google Drive/AddingProgram/AddingProgram.py", line 27, in callback
    result = int(ent1) + int(ent2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: its a good idea to try and print whatever is causing problems ... try adding `print ent1,":::",ent2` right before your result line

Comment: Your question's title could be improved remarkably. "cant seem to figure out what to do to make it work?" doesn't tell us anything about your problem, and doesn't attract experts to read the question. I'd recommend updating it with a short explanation of what your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
btnadd = Button(root, text="add", command=callback())
```

`callback` should not have parentheses here. That makes the function execute immediately instead of waiting for the button to be pressed.

```
btnadd = Button(root, text="add", command=callback)
```

---

Additionally, `if ent1 != 0 and ent2 != 0` is always going to evaluate to `True` because `ent1` and `ent2` are always strings, and a string is never equal to zero. Perhaps you meant `if ent1 != '' and ent2 != '':`, or just `if ent1 and ent2:`

---

Additionally, you should delete the `text` attributes from your Entry objects. I don't know what they're supposed to do since I don't see it listed in the documentation, but it looks like as long as they're both equal to one, typing in one entry will cause the same text to appear in the other entry.

---